# Make one value in enum required but only one

Tags: typescript

I have something that looks like this.

```
export enum TableCellType {
    Index = 'index',
    Text = 'text',
    Template = 'template',
}

export interface TableCell {
    class?: string;
}
```

I want the `TableCell` interface to make one of the values in the enum required, but if one is on the object, then disallow others.

Example:

`let a = {index: 2, text: 'hello'}`

This is not OK because two of the values from the enum is on the object. Only one can exist at any given time.

`let b = {text: 'This works'}`

This is ok since there are not multiple from the enum.

How do I go about typehinting this so that typescript understands?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it working for object literals (in addition, I specified the type for properties defined by TableCellType):

```ts
export enum TableCellType {
    Index = 'index',
    Text = 'text',
    Template = 'template',
}

type OneOfTableCellTypes = {index: number; text?: never; template?: never} 
  | {index?: never; text: string; template?: never}
  | {index?: never; text?: never; template: string}

export type TableCell = OneOfTableCellTypes & {
    class?: string;
}

let a: TableCell = {index: 2, text: 'hello'} // ERROR
let b: TableCell = {index: 2}                // OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwCoEMBGAbYAYWDzwwE8xg4BvAKDkbgElEATUOAXjgHIBLdqF4AaBkwyh4PXjCmjxjSajB4sc7nzkq1chQF86dGJWoB5RMDMAzbPiIkypgM6aagjiABccFKhzAUADccHIgMAD8PpYAboEh2qrqwFG%20wHFQ%20nDiAD60HqCpsfGhUj7OMFCCAOYJwDrJRemBhox57kIgTRl14d0librA5ZU1hnSgkLChppi4BMSkmhZWtvMOpBRUrgBktIpwAMZqzs6pFVWItXTjBPBYPnYLjm4F3nAATCKl4T68ABaOCC8LIAelBcAAogAlaFmaF0O5wHCPdaLPCvTo%20D5ZJh4-FMcFwMwAaToQA)

If you have more variants, you can go with:

```ts
type TableCellTypeMap = {
    index: number;
    text: string;
    template: string,
}

type ExcludeAllExcept<T, K extends keyof T> = {[Prop in keyof T]?: Prop extends K ? T[Prop]: never}
type oneOf<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> & ExcludeAllExcept<T, K>}[keyof T];

export type TableCell = oneOf<TableCellTypeMap> & {
    class?: string;
}

let a: TableCell = {index: 2, text: 'hello'} // ERROR
let b: TableCell = {index: 2}                // OK
```

[Playground with oneOf](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDYQMISUm4IFk5hQC8UA3gFBRVQCWAdgCYQAeAXFHQK4C2CEATgG5K1YC2DsAzsH70A5sOpQx3MEjhipM%20QBpyAX3LlQkKAFFmAYyScmAQUwXLEMMAA8MHVADSUcREZJKABrCBAAewAzWAA%20YjIAbQAFfnDCehCwqNgAXQB%20dhS0v2YxQJ8oPNhk1LAc9joIADcBQxNocMaAeUiPOJJSKATfDNCI6Jh6qCSaS2CPL284gDJzKxt7RysXd08fGP0EsezJ4XIWMHD%20YGUcWEQUdEx4zogejwe0DCwcfDAVsgiKjWOCSSQFKDSWR0BQGIwoG5wdjwZBfZ4DehMNhQABMXjEpXYAHIABbfcJE-RQAD01PMACV6V16eQEVAEMjPk8kPFSJiWOwcVSlCLRbSoF1vOQgA)

Unfortunately, this wont prevent you from assigning an incorrect object (having 2 properties) in runtime.

Comment: If the enum has 20 entries wouldn't this be hard to write?

Comment: @RameshReddy For 3 variants mentioned in OP I find manually constructed alternatives easier to understand, but I added a version working with an arbitrary number of variants.